# Cannot validate SharePoint URL in Visual Studio

Tags: development, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Using VS 2013 Update 4.  Office tools Udpated.
SharePoint 2013 installed locally.

I can browse the site as expected.

However, when I go to VS and try to create a solution I get this
[image]

I also cannot add an SP connection from the Server Explorer in VS.  I get a popup saying "A task was cancelled".

This is a new dev VM to replace an existing one.
It has SP, AD and VS all installed.

It doesn't seem to be an SP issue.  I have checked the service account, app pools, database permissions etc...All good there.

There is nothing in the event log and fiddler doesn't record any attempt to ping the site.

I think it has something to do with vssphostv5.exe.  I cannot find it in the task manager or process explorer.
I tried to run it manually and nothing.
I also tried to repair VS (this is a fresh install and the first project I am trying to create).

Despite taking hours to repair...the problem still persists.

Any ideas?  I'm out!

Comment: did you start vs as administrator? does the health analyzer show any errors in the Central Administration?

Comment: Yep - start as admin, always!!  HA does show a few, but only the regular "disk space" stuff you get on dev boxes.

Comment: ok but no missing features or such? I once had some strange problems with your error message which had to do with missing assembly errors in HA.

Comment: Nope, nothing like that.  It doesn't seem like VS has even got to SP.  The error pops up too fast :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a "loopback check" issue. There's two methods to resolve these detailed here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896861

Since this is a Dev VM I'd suggest the second method.

Comment: It's not this.  I've already disabled loopback check - pretty standard step for a dev vm!

Comment: It might be a "standard step for a dev vm", but your post does not mention that you have disabled it..

Comment: Fair point.  Loopback is disabled.  I did however state that I can browse the site as expected - which would not be the case if "loopback" was getting in the way.